# OutputProjectionWrapper vs fully connected layer on top of RNN

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I'm reading the 14th chapter of Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn and TensorFlow. It says:

> Although using an `OutputProjectionWrapper` is the simplest solution to reduce the dimensionality of the RNN’s output sequences down to just one value per time step (per instance), it is not the most efficient. There is a trickier but more efficient solution: you can reshape the RNN outputs, then apply a single fully connected layer with the appropriate output size. [...] This can provide a significant speed boost since there is just one fully connected layer instead of one per time step.

This makes no sense to me. In case of `OutputProjectionWrapper` we need to perform 2 operations per time step:

1. Calculate new hidden state based on previous hidden state and input.
2. Calculate output by applying dense layer to calculated hidden state.

Of course, when we use plain `BasicRNNCell` + dense layer on top, we need to do only one operation on each time step (the first one), but then we need to pipe each output tensor through our dense layer. So we need to perform the very same amount of operations in the both cases.

Also, I can't understand the following part:

> This can provide a significant speed boost since there is just one fully connected layer instead of one per time step.

Don't we have only one fully connected layer in both cases? As far as I understand `OutputProjectionWrapper` uses the same shared layer on each time step. I don't even know how it can create different layer for every time step because `OutputProjectionWrapper` has no information about the amount of time steps we will be using.

I will be very grateful if someone can explain the difference between these approaches.

**UPD** Here is pseudocode for the question. Am I missing something?

```py
# 2 time steps, x1 and x2 - inputs, h1 and h2 - hidden states, y1 and y2 - outputs.

# OutputProjectionWrapper
h1 = calc_hidden(x1, 0)
y1 = dense(h1)
h2 = calc_hidden(x2, h1)
y2 = dense(h2)

# BasicRNNCell + dense layer on top of all time steps
h1 = calc_hidden(x1, 0)
y1 = h1
h2 = calc_hidden(x2, h1)
y2 = h2

y1 = dense(y1)
y2 = dense(y2)
```

**UPD 2** I've created two small code snippets (one with `OutputProjectionWrapper` and another with `BasicRNNCell` and `tf.layers.dense` on top) - both created 14 variables with the same shape. So there is definitely no memory differences between these approaches.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is applying 1 layer to a tensor of shape (x, n) is faster than applying same layer to a tensor of shape (x) n times due to matrix multiplication optmizations.

Answer (score -1):

This webpage has a detailed explanation to your very question.

https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/neural-networks-and/9781492037354/ch04.html

Here is an excerpt from the above page. Hope this helps.

Although using an OutputProjectionWrapper is the simplest solution to reduce the dimensionality of the RNN’s output sequences down to just one value per time step (per instance), it is not the most efficient. There is a trickier but more efficient solution: you can reshape the RNN outputs from [batch_size, n_steps, n_neurons] to [batch_size * n_steps, n_neurons], then apply a single fully connected layer with the appropriate output size (in our case just 1), which will result in an output tensor of shape [batch_size * n_steps, n_outputs], and then reshape this tensor to [batch_size, n_steps, n_outputs]. These operations are represented in Figure 4-10.

Comment: I believe this is exactly the post which the OP has asked clarification for. Reiterating the same explanation doesn't seem to provide any help.